# Is there a way to detect data traffic in an Internet Explorer window with AutoIt?

Tags: internet-explorer, network-programming, fiddler, autoit

Is there a way to detect and save incoming and outgoing data through an Internet Explorer window with AutoIt like an Event Listener or Fiddler ?

Or is there any other way to do this with another browser ?

Comment: It's probably best to use existing tools especially made for sniffing like wireshark.

Comment: You could easily use AutoIt to drive both the browser Window and Fiddler. Or you could build an application atop FiddlerCore and drive that.

Comment: @EricLaw i think i need more robust solution then inspecting browser window or fiddler with autoit. it will prevent the user from using his computer. it should be robust like fiddler2.

Comment: If you need a robust solution, then why not use Wireshark like Johannes suggest - or take a look at http://www.charlesproxy.com/